# Zero State, Stable Equilibrium, Dynamic System

Tags: linear-algebra, dynamical-systems, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Could someone please help?

The question reads:
For which real numbers $k$ is the zero state a stable equilibrium of the dynamic system 
$x_{t+1} = Ax_t$?

$A = \begin{bmatrix} 0.1 &k \\ 0.3 & 0.3 \end{bmatrix}$

So, my thought is I need to find the eigenvalues.  In  order to do this I calculated the characteristic polynomial as

$x^2 - 0.4x + 0.03 - 0.3k = 0$,  with $x$ representing eigenvalues.

Using the quadratic formula I found that the (real) eigenvalues are 
$$x = \frac{2 \pm \sqrt{1+30k}}{10}$$
and for the zero state to be in stable equilibrium $\sqrt{1+30k}<8$.  Hence, $k<21/10$ (for stable equilibrium).

My question is how do I figure out the values for $k$ if the eigenvalues are complex?

Do I solve the inequality $\sqrt{-1-30k} < 8$?

Thanks!

Comment: Just so you know, I reformatted your question using LaTeX for easier viewing.

Comment: For the real case, you also need $k\geq \cfrac{-1}{30}$ to keep them real.

Comment: You're quite welcome.  Glad it was helpful.

Answer (score 4):

In general, the zero state of a dynamical system of the form $x_{t+1} = Ax_t$ is a stable equilibrium when all of the eigenvalues of $A$ are inside the unit circle in the complex plane.  So if you have an eigenvalue of the form $a+bi$, you get stability when $a^2 + b^2 < 1$.  Since this is a homework question, I'll let you work out the rest of the problem from here.  (This isn't going to be equivalent to solving $\sqrt{-1-30k} < 8$, though.)

Comment: Good answer. Just to be clear, though, one has *asymptotic* stability if $a^2 + b^2 <1$.  The system is generally considered stable if $a^2 + b^2 = 1$.

Comment: So, a = 2 and b= sqrt(-1-30k)?  With this I get: 4 + -1 - 30k < 10 which leads to 3 - 30k < 10.  Therefore, if the eigenvalues are complex k < -7/30 ????

Comment: sorry.... k > -7/30

Comment: @user5430: you lost the denominator of 10 in your expressions for a and b.  As Mike said, you then need to compare a^2+b^2 with 1.

Comment: @user5430:  You should also ask the question what happens if $k=-7/30$.

Comment: Oops - I didn't notice the lost factor of 10.

Comment: @Ross: Can I not multiply both sides by 10?  Am I being stupid here?  Very possible; I forget the last time I had more than 4hrs of sleep at once  :)

Comment: @user5430:  but the 10 gets squared when you square a and b

Comment: Thanks Ross!  Then I get sqrt((2/10)^2+(1/10 sqrt(-1-30 k))^2) < 1 which leads to 1/10 sqrt(3-30 k) < 1 and in the end k > -97/30.

Comment: @Ross: Thanks for handling the OP's questions while I was away from my computer.

Comment: @user5430: Writing 1/10 sqrt(3-30 k) is a good way to get confused about what is divided by what.  sqrt(3-30 k)/10 is clearer. k>-97/30 is correct, but you need k small enough that the roots are complex.  See my comment above about the real case.

Comment: @Mike: you're welcome.